# Java.JoptionPane

Tags: java

Создаю два класса, использую ООP.
В первом классе `Course` cозданы переменные объекта, методы `set` и `get`.
Во втором классе `TuitionObjectStyle` созданы два объекта.

Я хочу через диалоговое окно `JOptionPane` запросить у юзера информацию и заполнить информацию по двум разным курсам.

Каким образом мне сохранить полученную информацию в переменной класса? Конструктор не предусмотрен. Есть три различные переменные типа `string`, `int`, `int`.

```
package cs520.hw2.part1;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TuitionObjectStyle extends Course {
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Course course1 = new Course();
        Course course2 = new Course();
        
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the name of the course: ");
        
        
        
    }
 
}
```

Comment: а что Коллекции  запретили использовать ?

Comment: Так а в чем проблема не понятно

Comment: К сожалению я только начала изучать язык, слово коллекции мне ни о чем не говорит. Прописываю course1.courseName = input.setName(); Ругается, что метод set не используется для String. Как сохранить ответ юзера в переменной courseName?

Comment: Ok, я нашла решение. Нужно прописать course1.courseName = input.substring(0); Где course1 это созданный объект, courseName  переменная объекта, input.substring(0); читает диалоговое окно в которое внесена информация и вырезает ее начиная с нулевого символа.